# How to extend the Play2 scala zentasks authentication to automatically get the user

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

In the zentasks example for Play2 we have the method

```
def isAuthenticated(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = {
  Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
    Action(request => f(user)(request))
  }
}
```

What I would like to do is add another method that I could use if I wanted to get the user directly from the database.

It gets a little boring having to add a wrapper in all methods

```
def method() = isAuthenticated { username => implicit request =>
  UserDAO.findOneByEmail(username).map { user =>
    Ok(html.user.view(user))
  }.getOrElse(Forbidden)
}
```

I'm new to functional programming and all these `=>` is making my head spin :)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define another method, for example `IsAuthenticatedUser`, which would take a parameter of type `User => Request[AnyContent] => Result`:

```scala
def IsAuthenticatedUser(f: User => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = IsAuthenticated { email => request =>
  UserDAO.findOneByEmail(email).map { user =>
    f(user)(request)
  }.getOrElse(Forbidden)
}
```

You can then use it like as follows:

```scala
def method = IsAuthenticatedUser { user => request =>
  Ok(html.user.view(user))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This was the final solution

```
trait Secured {

  def username(request: RequestHeader) = request.session.get(Security.username)

  def onUnauthorized(request: RequestHeader) = Results.Redirect(routes.Application.login)

  def withAuth(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = {
    Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
      Action(request => f(user)(request))
    }
  }

  def withUser(f: User => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = withAuth { username => implicit request =>
    UserDAO.findOneByUsername(username).map { user =>
      f(user)(request)
    }.getOrElse(onUnauthorized(request))
  }

}
```

Usage:

```
object Application extends Controller with Secured {

  def index = withAuth { username => implicit request =>
    Ok(html.index(username))
  }

  def user() = withUser { user => implicit request =>
    val username = user.username
    Ok(html.user(user))
  }
}
```

As you can see, if the session doesn't exist, the user gets redirected to the login page as specified in the trait.

And same goes if the username can't be found in the DAO.

Answer (score 1):

Semi-solution is to encapsulate fetching user data steps into some function and calling it from template level (not on each action), as every template is just a scala function.

Thanks to this approach if you have several actions using the same view (or even layout) you don't have to fetch logged user everytime ie:

in the `user view`:

```
@defining(Application.getLoggedUser){ user =>
    @yourlayout("Welcome") {
        <h2>Hello @user.name</h2>
        ...
    } 
}
```