# Can someone explain what the following code snippets means in Play framework (Scala)?

Tags: scala, forms-authentication, action, playframework-2.0

Please take a look at the following code

Application.scala

```
def Online = Action { implicit request =>
loginForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
  formWithErrors => BadRequest(html.login(formWithErrors)),
  user => Contact.AddOnline("email" -> user._1)
)
```

followed by

```
trait Secured {

  /**
  * Retrieve the connected user email.
  */
  private def username(request: RequestHeader) =
   request.session.get("email")

  /**
  * Redirect to login if the user in not authorized.
  */
  private def onUnauthorized(request: RequestHeader) = 
  Home.flashing("failure"->"You    are not logged in");

 // --

   /** 
   * Action for authenticated users.
   */
  def IsAuthenticated(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result)=
  Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
  Action(request => f(user)(request))
  }
```

--
My Problem is I am trying to call a piece of code called `setOnline(user.email)`. This code sets a certain user's status as online only after he is authenticated. In the above given code I would like to call my `setOnline(user.email)` function but I am not sure where or how I should call. I have been trying for the past 4 hours without any luck. The main problem is I do not understand how the above piece of code works completely (as it is not my code).

Comment: @biesior http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144393/how-to-extend-the-play2-scala-zentasks-authentication-to-automatically-get-the-u
 I am trying to use something similar as in this post. However, now I want to call a function that sets a certain value into the database. Do you have any suggestions on how this can be done. The main problem for me is I am not able to figure out where and how to call the function

Answer (score 1):

This code....

```
def Online = Action { implicit request =>
loginForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
  formWithErrors => BadRequest(html.login(formWithErrors)),
  user => Contact.AddOnline("email" -> user._1)
)
```

is an action that binds a request to a Form object called loginForm.  It will check to see if the form has errors, if it does then it will display the form with those errors.  If not, then it will invoke Contact.AddOnline.

And this...

```
def IsAuthenticated(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = 
    Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>Action(request => f(user)(request))
```

is an Action that wraps itself around another action ([action composition](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/ScalaActionsComposition)) to determine if the given username is authenticated or not.  If it is not authorized, then it will invoke the "onUnauthorized" function which will flash "You    are not logged in".  Which in reality will not work.  You should write your "onUnauthorized" similar to this...

```
 private def onUnauthorized(request: RequestHeader) = 
  Redirect(routes.Home.url).flashing("You    are not logged in")
```